# Using serial over lan with python

Tags: python, api, networking, serial-port

I'd like to write a python script to gather data from serial over lan but I can't seem to find a place to start with IPMI.  I've looked at OpenIPMI's python bindings but there doesn't seem to be any documentation.  Perhaps I can use the subprocess module and ipmitool?  I'm not sure that would be simple though.  Does anyone have any experience with this? How can I capture serial over lan data in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/ipmitool-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01445.html) that has a sample OpenIPMI python program?

And the [OpenIPMI documentation (pdf)](http://openipmi.sourceforge.net/IPMI.pdf)?

Comment: I looked at the pdf and thread but I can't seem to find much on serial over lan.  It looks like OpenIPMI might not support serial (section 3.10 in the pdf).